# How to left align window title in Windows 8 / 2012?

Tags: wpf, windows-8

Is there a way to (intrinsically) left align window title in Windows 8 or 2012 machine?

The Window's title in Window 8 or 2012 is horizontally center-aligned.

[image]

We have a WPF application that is ported to Windows 8 / 2012 machine. We are testing it along with couple of our clients and the clients need the title of the window to be left aligned as it was in Window 7 or XP.

I know we can do this using ControlTemplate in WPF but that would be too much for this little thing.

I am sure this is question is going to come up as more applications are ported to Windows 8 / 2012.

Is there any quick solution to this? Or do you know if Microsoft is going to give this flexibility in final releases of Windows 8 or 2012?

Comment: Did you mean Windows Server 2012?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All window titles in Windows 8 are center aligned. Forcing an application title to be left aligned in Windows 8 would be almost like forcing the minimize and maximize buttons to show up on the left side of the window.

You may be able to accomplish this using a custom draw window like DXWindow from DevExpress. See this post:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q298641.aspx

However, the application will appear out of place on Windows 8 and may not pass desktop application certification.

Comment: I agree. Its just the way people are used to and would like the application to appear exactly the same on all OSes :).

Comment: If you want "the application to appear exactly the same on all OSes" you should be using a web app, not WPF.

Answer (score 5):

It is the default behavior of Windows 8, so it isn't advised.

ALTHOUGH Visual Studio 2012 left-aligns the titles, so it is possible, however inconsistent it may be.

[image]

It's doubtful Microsoft will offer up how to override the default functionality or change it since it is already RTM.  [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/437938/Center-Align-the-TExt-of-Form-Title-Bar) may help you get some of the way.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 uses a custom window chrome, which is why it has free reign to left-align the window title.

Comment: I read somewhere that Microsoft will bring back Aero in Windows 10. Might they revert this centering thing as part of that? Here's hoping.