# Left align winforms heading text

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am working on vb.net windows form application in visual studio 2010. My form heading always am getting in center of form.

My windows form like this:
[image]

Is there a way to left align my form text.

I want to get this **form1** in left side of my form

In load event I given code like this:

```
 Me.Text = "     form1"
 Me.Text = Me.Text.Trim()
```

But I am getting my form heading in center only

Comment: sir i want to get my heading in left side..so where i have to give space

Comment: in load event i give code like this: Me.Text = "    form1"
        Me.Text = Me.Text.Trim()  but i am getting heading in center only

Comment: I have deleted my comments because, apparently, there wasn't any heading-spaces issues and the header's text is shown in the center by default ?! (as confirmed by NidZaaaa). Not sure about the exact configuration allowing such thing to happen; if I create a new winforms app with VS 2010, the default behaviour is left (or right RightToLeft is true). So... no idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to left align window title in Windows 8 / 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824181/how-to-left-align-window-title-in-windows-8-2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
        Dim startingPoint As Double = (Me.Width / 2) - (g.MeasureString(Me.Text.Trim, Me.Font).Width / 2)
        Dim widthOfASpace As Double = g.MeasureString(" ", Me.Font).Width
        Dim tmp As String = " "
        Dim tmpWidth As Double = 0

        Do
            tmp += " "
            tmpWidth += widthOfASpace
        Loop While (tmpWidth + widthOfASpace) < startingPoint

        Me.Text = Me.Text.Trim & tmp
```

This worked great for me.
Also, [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93959/WinForm-Extended) might be helpful.

Comment: ?! Can you please explain me how is this supossed to make the Text on the left-hand side? It actually moves it to the right hand side (unless RightToLeft = yes). But in any case... why you want to add more blank spaces? If the blank spaces are the problem of the OP, why not deleting them (via trim())? Don't understand the point of this answer at all.

Comment: actually i want to show my form heading left hand side of the page,,what i can do for that?

Comment: I just edited my code. This is only way of doing this without using third-party .dll.
The point is that you have to add custom empty spaces in this case.

Comment: @user3106114 I have told you already various times: the text is shown on the left hand side by default you don't need to do anything. The only reason why you see it in a different position is because you are writing a bunch of heading spaces. The solution? Don't write this spaces (or delete them afterwards, via Trim() as suggested). If you don't remove the adding-blank-spaces part, there is no possible solution for your problem as far as you are precisely telling "Form1" to not be displayed on the left hand side. If you don't know what you are doing wrong, post your WHOLE code.

Comment: Actually, the default position of Form Text is Centered.  
I edited my answer once again, I've added a link to CodeProject where you can see some samples

Comment: Then we are going somewhere... you seem to have the same configuration than the OP; for me the default position is left (or right). Please, describe your exact conditions such that we all can understand what is happening here. Also if you default position is centered, your code does not make any sense either.

Comment: It does make sense, since you're are adding empty spaces after Me.Text.Trim and you are basically pushin your Form Title to left side (Remember: I edited my code), you can give it a try also.  
It would be very usefull if you could let us know how can we change default position of Form Title?

Comment: No problem @user3106114 please mark this answer as correct if that helped you so other can find it easily when they need it.

Comment: No idea. This was the whole point of my first comment. I thought that the form is always left aligned (unless you select RightToLeft). I am using VS 2010 and I am not able to reproduce your conditions (text being centered).

Comment: That's wierd, really. Default position of Form Title is center in VS 2005/2010/2012/2013, I was using all of them and it was allways the same. Really wierd.

Comment: I am observing left-aligned in all the versions 2008/2010/2012. Every time I have created a C# or VB.NET application (winforms) during the last 5 years, so.. your statement is a bit confusing to me. Also what is the effect of the RightToLeft property?!

Comment: The difference is probably Windows 7 and Windows 8. Windows 8 and 8.1 has the Form header in the center by default while Windows 7 has it aligned on the left.

Comment: Compare Win8: http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/windows-8-desktop-interface-color-changfe.jpg  and Win 7: http://www.lawes-world.de/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/windows7-nach-install.jpg

Comment: @Jens I've been using in both, win7 and win8/8.1

Comment: @varovarbas when I use LeftToRight it move it on the right side of title bar.

Comment: @Jens It makes kind of sense as far as I am using Windows 7 (and never used Windows 8). In any case it is a bit weird the OP to change the properties I write in my application (and I observed left-aligned in XP and Vista) but well... I have seen weirdest things.

Comment: (my nick is varoCarbas) See? This makes sense. If you set LeftToRight to "yes", it shows on the right; and to "no" on the left (why on the center?). Anyway...

Comment: @varocarbas first of all sorry for misspelling your nickname.
Anyway, when I set LeftToRight without my code title is still in the middle of form.
Maybe that is wierd to you, but it's also wierd to me your settings since this is the first time I heard about that. And yeah, I've tried using this in my application it works right as it should (Place form title to left side without any problem)

Comment: BTW it seems like you should take a look at your code as far as it does not work as expected; the idea is fine but it got messed up in some of your updates and right now it does not deliver what you want. Please, correct it such that I can +1 your answer (even though I am not able to replicate the conditions, the algorithm might be helpful for left-aligning purposes).

Comment: @varocarbas It's not needed to edit/correct anything since it's working more then fine. Btw, I would really like to know how to setup my default position to be in the left/right since that would be VERY usefull.

Comment: Do whatever you want but it is wrong. You spending quite a few "effort" into calculating the required number of blank spaces tmpWidth + widthOfASpace and then you use just a hardcoded value (tmp). Delete the hardcoding or all the calculations, otherwise your code would include lots of redundants bits and will not +1 worthy IMO (not right enough).

Comment: @nidzaa...after changing form windows state property ,normal to Maximized the page heading not getting proper left side,,

Comment: Regarding setting to left by default, as said, no idea why it is not the case with you (perhaps a CultureInfo issue? With Spain and UK works left).

Comment: @user3106114 understand what the proposed code does: it adds all the required extra-spaces at the right. If the width changes, more extra spaces are required and thus you would have to use this code again (for example: add it to the Form1_SizeChanged event).

Comment: sir i added the same code in Form1_SizeChanged ,,but still getting same result,,not reflected

Comment: @user3106114 as Varovarbas said to you, this is hardcoded left alignment so with different sizes of forms you have to changed the number of empty spaces you set in `tmp += "    "`

Comment: @varocarbas you might be right, probably it's about CultureInfo, and since I'm using US culture that might be different then in UK.

Comment: (I insist, my nick is varoCarbas). Your last suggestion to the OP does not seem to be too helpful: how is the OP expected two how much should he vary the number of empty spaces? Your original code (without the hardcoding) might have work perfectly from the Form_SizeChanged event. But I guess that I have insisted too much (actually, I shouldn't be doing this kind of things; I will better reduce my contribution to answers)

Comment: @varocarbas I'm sorry, once again for misspelling. You're right that can vary depends on Form Size and also on Screen Resolution. But, for now I don't see any different way of doing this, really.

Comment: @user3106114 You are doing it right but the algorithm is not (well... actually, it consists in two parts; one of them is right but is not in use). You should correct it by your own (you should know what this algorithm is doing instead of applying it blindly) or ask  Nidzaaaa to correct it for you. As said, enough of my help here. Hope that Nidzaaaa will be able to help you completely out.

Comment: @varocarbas feel free to edit my answer as it should be.

Comment: Btw, this approach will probably not work well for larger windows due to a limitation in the length of the Form's title string.

Comment: @Jens yup, seems like this is a problem solver only for smaller forms.

Comment: @user3106114 check the link I gave you, that might be more usefull for larger forms.

Comment: The immediate fixing is converting `tmp += "lots of spaces"` into `tmp += "just one space"` to make the code coherent. Your loop iterates as a function of widthOfASpace which is calculated from `"just one space"` not from `"lots of spaces"`. But this is not all: your code ignores relevant factors (length of buttons, borders, paddings, etc.); this together with the fact that I cannot test it, makes me reject your offer (I might edit to deliver a for-sure-working solution). Sorry about that.

Comment: @varocarbas I'm sorry, I think that I sounded little unfriendly in our previous conversation. THat was not my idea, sorry once again. Honestly, I am not the guy who is professional and the guy who is doing this for a lot of years. I posted the answer that helped me once long time ago, but in that case I was using smaller forms and that for temporary solution. In 100% of cases I'm using default alignment of Form Title text, and seems like that if you want to make it default you have to change CulturalInfo of your VS or computer. But that could make you a lot of problems later.

Comment: No problem. I might also be a bit impatient lately after having had problems with some people here some weeks ago.

Comment: @varocarbas please if you have better solution post it or just edit my answer so the guy who asked this question can solve the problem easily, but I think it's not that easy to do it in this way.

Comment: There is no easy solution (as said, you have to account for all the elements of the form which might affect the location of the title). The only reason why I started commenting here was not being aware of the center-aligned option and just thinking that the OP mistaken wrote heading spaces. I am leaving now and, in any case, I don't like too much to post answers I cannot validate (much less in a situation which might become pretty complex as this one). You can correct your code (make it coherent as suggested) and add a comment talking about the limitations of the approach.

Comment: Your (potentially corrected) code + bordless form + no padding + width of buttons (might be a hardcoded approximation) might deliver close to acceptable results. Correct your answer such that all this is reflected and might be OK.